# Proving a maximal element of a certain set of ideals is prime.

Tags: modules

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and let $M$ be a nonzero $R$-module. If $m\in M$, define $\operatorname{ord}(m) =
\{r \in R \mid rm = 0\}$, and define $F = \{\operatorname{ord}(m) \mid m \in M\ \wedge m \neq 0\}$. Prove that every maximal
element in $F$ is a prime ideal.

Comment: Hi new user! $$\color{blue}{\large{\text{Welcome to Math.SE!}}}$$ Don't worry about it now but you might like to know that we use [Mathjax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) here (e.g. `$\theta$` for $\theta$). Also, please show your working so far :)

Comment: Hi: welcome to math.SE! The community generally discourages posts that just state problems, and encourages posts that ask questions and show all partial progress on the poster's part. That way they can get quality answers. Please add your thoughts up to now in your post to improve your chances of getting a good answer.

Comment: Please edit the title to be an actual title, not a statement of the full problem...

Comment: Let be M a maximal ideal of F. We have to show that M is a prime ideal. M is maximal , results that there are no other ideals contained between M and R .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints:**

$ord(m)$ is an ideal for every $m\in M$, so in particular the maximal elements are ideals. This follows from routine verification of the ideal axioms.

Suppose $ord(m)$ is maximal in that set, and that $ab\in ord(m)$. If $b\notin ord(m)$, then what can you say about $bm$?

Then what can you say about $ord(bm)$ in relation to $ord(m)$?

After answering these, one will be able to see why $am=0$.

Comment: If ab ∈ ord(m) then abm=0 . But if b ∉ ord(m) this implies that mb !=0. and a=0. Am i right until now ?

Comment: The first two claims are right, but the last claim ($a=0$) is wrong. You have not related $ord(bm)$ to $ord(m)$, which is a critical step.

Comment: ord(bm) is included in ord(m) because ord(m) is maximal ?

Comment: @user112127 No, that reasoning alone is wrong. "Maximal" doesn't mean that it contains everything else. You're on the right track though: determine which one contains the other, and then what that means for $ord(bm)$. Your question mark makes you sound like you are *guessing*. Don't guess... look at what is actually the case!

Comment: ord(m) contains ord(bm)

Comment: this implies that r which is an element of ord(bm) is the form r1*c , where r1 ∈ord(m)

Comment: @user112127 If you say "$ord(m)$ contains $ord(bm)$" then you are saying that $x(bm)=0$ implies $xm=0$, which is not obviously true. This isn't the right path. How about you look at the opposite containment?

Comment: so ord(bm) contains ord(m)

Comment: this implies that xm=0 where x is an element of ord(xm)

Comment: @user112127 $ord(bm)\supseteq ord(m)$ is the right path, but you haven't supplied any proof and it still sounds like you're guessing. In your final result you'll have to carefully explain why these things are true.

Comment: can you give me another hint please ?

Comment: i don't know how to prove that am=0

Comment: we know that ord(bm)⊇ord(m) this implies that an element of ord(m) belongs to ord(bm) .let x be an element of ord(m) . xm=0 and x(bm)=0 but bm!=0

Comment: am i right with this  ?

Comment: @user112127 First tell me how you know ord(bm) contains ord(m), and then I'll give hints.

Comment: We have to prove that an element of ord(m) is in ord(bm). Let be x an element of ord(m). xm=0. Multiplied with b and this results xmb=0=x(mb)=0  . So x is in ord(mb) . So ord(mb) contains ord(m)

Comment: @user112127 Right! Good work! So you have $ord(m)\subseteq ord(mb)\subsetneq R$. What does ord(m)'s maximality imply?

Comment: ord(bm)=R from the definition

Comment: @user112127 No, that's not possible since $1\in R$ does not annihilate $bm$. What's the other possibility?

Comment: ord(m)=ord(bm) .am i right ?

Comment: @user112127 Correct, that is the only possibility. You already said once before that $a\in ord(bm)$. What else do we know now about $a$?

Comment: a ∈ ord(m) . and this is what we want. But i have one question.

Comment: a ∈ord(bm) because abm=0 ?

Comment: @user112127 $a\in ord(m)$, Right, and thus we've finished verifying $ord(m)$ is prime! For your second question, yes $a\in ord(bm)$ because $a(bm)=0$. That is the definition of $ord(bm)$ :) Congratulations! I now believe you see all the steps clearly!

Comment: Yes. Thank you very much !